# Changing one inner list's element changes all inner lists python

Tags: python

Basically, this is what I've got:

```
In [1]: list1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0]] * 10

In [2]: list1
Out[2]: 
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [3]: list1[0][1] = 9

In [4]: list1
Out[4]: 
[[0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 9, 0, 0]]
```

When trying to change the second element of the first list to 9, I somehow changed all first elements to 9. How did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is shallow copy, just copy reference.
Try `list1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0] for _ in range(10)]`